# Laravels Storage::put() appends string to the path

Tags: laravel

I normally use Laravels Storage facade like this. However now it for some reason appends random string to my path name, which results in my path name being a folder and filename being a random string.

```
public static function storeFile(&$va, $file)
{
    $rs = generateRandomString(12);
    $va['path'] = "{$va['path_base']}_{$rs}_0.{$va['ext']}";
    $va['path_thumb'] = $va['path'];

    $q = Storage::disk('s3')->put($va['path'], $file);

    dd($q, $va['path'], $va['path_thumb'], $file);

    $file = File::create($va);
}
```

dd:
[image: dd]

How is the string getting appended? How to stop it?

Comment: use `putAs`, `put` is specifically asking you pass it a path, not a filename.

Comment: `Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::putAs()`

Comment: `Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs($path, $file, $name)`

Comment: thank you, this works. in the meantime i also found `$file->storeAs($va['folder_path'], $va['file_name'], 's3');`. but im still perplexed that it worked in one service class and i have to do it differently in another one.